# JHipster: Add Angular dependency 'angular-2-dropdown-multiselect'

Tags: angular, drop-down-menu, jhipster, multi-select

i am trying to use the [angular-2-dropdown-multiselect](https://github.com/softsimon/angular-2-dropdown-multiselect) in a JHipster 4.3.0 application that uses Angular, not AngularJS.

I added the dependency via yarn as described in the README.md, generated by JHipster: `yarn add --exact angular-2-dropdown-multiselect`

I also added the following to vendor.js: `import 'angular-2-dropdown-multiselect/bundles/dropdown.umd.js';`

I also tried: `import 'angular-2-dropdown-multiselect';`

Besides that i also tried to add `'angular2-infinite-scroll'` to the vendor array in webpack.vendor.js.

The `MultiselectDropdownModule` is also to added to my `@NgModule`. The dependency seems to be available, as i can access `IMultiSelectOption` in my controller code without any errors. The problem i have is, that the the html component `ss-multiselect-dropdown` does not seem to be available. I get the following error:

`vendor.dll.js:1514 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: No value accessor for form control with name: 'gameSelector'
Error: No value accessor for form control with name: 'gameSelector'
    at _throwError (http://localhost:9000/vendor.dll.js:21824:11) [angular]
    at setUpControl (http://localhost:9000/vendor.dll.js:21737:9) [angular]
    at NgModel._setUpStandalone (http://localhost:9000/vendor.dll.js:24306:9) [angular]
    at NgModel._setUpControl (http://localhost:9000/vendor.dll.js:24292:37) [angular]
    at NgModel.ngOnChanges (http://localhost:9000/vendor.dll.js:24223:18) [angular]
    at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (http://localhost:9000/vendor.dll.js:11185:19) [angular]
    at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (http://localhost:9000/vendor.dll.js:12566:17) [angular]
    at checkAndUpdateNode (http://localhost:9000/vendor.dll.js:12534:16) [angular]
    at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (http://localhost:9000/vendor.dll.js:13163:59) [angular]
    at debugCheckDirectivesFn (http://localhost:9000/vendor.dll.js:13104:13) [angular]
    at Object.View_RequestComponent_0.co [as updateDirectives] (ng:///EdgeServiceRequestModule/RequestComponent.ngfactory.js:992:5) [angular]
    at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (http://localhost:9000/vendor.dll.js:13089:21) [angular]
    at checkAndUpdateView (http://localhost:9000/vendor.dll.js:12501:14) [angular]
    at callViewAction (http://localhost:9000/vendor.dll.js:12816:17) [angular]
    at _throwError (http://localhost:9000/vendor.dll.js:21824:11) [angular]
    at setUpControl (http://localhost:9000/vendor.dll.js:21737:9) [angular]
    at NgModel._setUpStandalone (http://localhost:9000/vendor.dll.js:24306:9) [angular]
    at NgModel._setUpControl (http://localhost:9000/vendor.dll.js:24292:37) [angular]
    at NgModel.ngOnChanges (http://localhost:9000/vendor.dll.js:24223:18) [angular]
    at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (http://localhost:9000/vendor.dll.js:11185:19) [angular]
    at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (http://localhost:9000/vendor.dll.js:12566:17) [angular]
    at checkAndUpdateNode (http://localhost:9000/vendor.dll.js:12534:16) [angular]
    at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (http://localhost:9000/vendor.dll.js:13163:59) [angular]
    at debugCheckDirectivesFn (http://localhost:9000/vendor.dll.js:13104:13) [angular]
    at Object.View_RequestComponent_0.co [as updateDirectives] (ng:///EdgeServiceRequestModule/RequestComponent.ngfactory.js:992:5) [angular]
    at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (http://localhost:9000/vendor.dll.js:13089:21) [angular]
    at checkAndUpdateView (http://localhost:9000/vendor.dll.js:12501:14) [angular]
    at callViewAction (http://localhost:9000/vendor.dll.js:12816:17) [angular]
    at resolvePromise (http://localhost:9000/polyfills.bundle.js:4885:31) [angular]
    at resolvePromise (http://localhost:9000/polyfills.bundle.js:4856:17) [angular]
    at http://localhost:9000/polyfills.bundle.js:4933:17 [angular]
    at Object.onInvokeTask (http://localhost:9000/vendor.dll.js:4565:37) [angular]
    at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:9000/polyfills.bundle.js:4570:36) [angular]
    at Zone.webpackJsonp../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (http://localhost:9000/polyfills.bundle.js:4338:47) [<root> => angular]
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (http://localhost:9000/polyfills.bundle.js:4766:35) [<root>]
    at <anonymous> [<root>]`

Did i miss anything? Do i have to configure it differently?

Thanks a lot for your answers in advance!

Comment: thi error has nothing to do with the npm packet you added: it's your reactive form wich is misconfiguret. Google "No value accessor for form control" for more info, seems you have a formElelemt wich is'nt a know - standard - form element. Most probably your new select element. Have you understood and followed the instructions on the component's readme? you have to use "ss-multiselect-dropdown" instead of "select" in the html template and manage otions data manually in ts file.